# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1-\cos \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n}}}{1+\cos \frac{i\pi}{\sqrt{2n}}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

We may have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1-\cos \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n}}}{1+\cos \frac{i\pi}{\sqrt{2n}}}&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\cos \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\cos \frac{i\pi}{\sqrt{2n}}}\\&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\pi^2}{4n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\cos^2 \frac{i\pi}{2\sqrt{2n}}},
\end{align*}
but how to go on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit doesn't exist (i.e. it is infinite).

For $1\leqslant k\leqslant m_n:=\lfloor\sqrt{n/8}\rfloor$ (and $n$ large enough), let $$i_k:=\lfloor(2k-1)\sqrt{2n}\rfloor=(2k-1)\sqrt{2n}-\epsilon_k.$$ Then $$\cos^2\frac{i_k\pi}{2\sqrt{2n}}=\cos^2\left((2k-1)\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\epsilon_k\pi}{\sqrt{8n}}\right)=\sin^2\frac{\epsilon_k\pi}{\sqrt{8n}}\leqslant\frac{\pi^2}{8n},$$ hence $$\frac{\pi^2}{4n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\cos^2\frac{i\pi}{2\sqrt{2n}}}\geqslant\frac{\pi^2}{4n}\sum_{k=1}^{m_n}\frac{1}{\cos^2\frac{i_k\pi}{2\sqrt{2n}}}\geqslant 2m_n\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\infty.$$

Comment: Thanks! What about$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1-\cos \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n}}}{1\color{red}{-}\cos \frac{i\pi}{\sqrt{2n}}}?$$

Comment: @mengdie1982: The same (take $i_k=\lfloor 2k\sqrt{2n}\rfloor$ this time).

Comment: A solution goes as follows \begin{align*} L:&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1-\cos \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{1-\cos \frac{i\pi}{\sqrt{2n}}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\pi^2}{4n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sin^2 \frac{i\pi}{2\sqrt{2n}}}\\ &=\lim_{n \to \infty}2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i^2\left(\frac{2\sqrt{2n}}{i\pi}\sin \frac{i\pi}{2\sqrt{2n}}\right)^2}=2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{i^2\left(\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{i\pi}\sin \frac{i\pi}{2\sqrt{2n}}\right)^2}\\ &=2\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{3}. \end{align*}  Where is the mistake?

Comment: @mengdie1982: How do you justify the interchange of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ and $\sum$ here? [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) (or, more specifically, [Tannery's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem), which is simply a discrete version of it) is inapplicable. And *my* reasoning remains correct.